# Как отрисовать в Image двумерный массив со значениями?

Tags: c#, bitmap

Есть массив 512x424 заполненный числами от 0 до 10000. Требуется изобразить массив графически, то есть метод должен принимать двумерный массив со значениями, а на выходе должен быть получен битмап.

Вот мой код метода отрисовки из одномерного массива (получение массива глубин с помощью сенсора Kinect)

```
private void OnDepthFrameArrived(object sender, DepthFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var refer = e.FrameReference;
        var frame = refer?.AcquireFrame();
        if (frame == null) return;

        using (frame)
        {
            var frameDesc = frame.FrameDescription;
            var width = frame.FrameDescription.Width;
            var height = frame.FrameDescription.Height;
            var min2Depth = frame.DepthMinReliableDistance;
            var max2Depth = frame.DepthMaxReliableDistance;
            var pixelData = new byte[width*height*(PixelFormats.Bgr32.BitsPerPixel + 7)/8];

            frame.CopyFrameDataToArray(_depthData);

             var colorIndex = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < _depthData.Length; i++)
            {
                var depth = _depthData[i];
                var x = i % _desc.Width;
                var y = i / _desc.Width;
                _mapArrayDepth[x, y] = depth;
            }
            _centDepth = (ushort) _mapArrayDepth[256, 212];
             foreach (
                var intensity in
                    _depthData.Select(depth => (byte)(depth >= min2Depth && depth <= max2Depth ? depth : 0)))
            {
                 pixelData[colorIndex++] = intensity; // Blue
                 pixelData[colorIndex++] = intensity; // Green
                 pixelData[colorIndex++] = intensity; // Red

                 ++colorIndex;

            }

            _depthBitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, frameDesc.Width, frameDesc.Height),
            pixelData,
            frameDesc.Width * _bytePerPixel,
            0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: оттенками серого, что ли? Сделайте поиск на "Fifty shades of grey".

Comment: Оттенков серого 256 - от белого до черного. То есть примерно 40 значений будут одного цвета.

Comment: @Igor Именно так и нужно.

Comment: Прекрасно. Покажите, пожалуйста, Ваш код и опишите возникшие трудности.

Comment: вставьте код в вопрос и переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы там было что-то и про задачу, и про написанный код (что ожидается на выходе, что получается, в чём проблема/вопрос).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

```
// source - исходный массив
Bitmap CreateBitmap(int[,] source)
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(source.GetLength(0), source.GetLength(1));
    for (var i = 0; i < bitmap.Height; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < bitmap.Width; j++)
            bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(source[i, j])); // вместо Color.FromArgb можете использовать любой другой способ преобразования элемента массива в цвет

    return bitmap;
}
```

Если захотите его ускорить, то смотрите в сторону [Bitmap.LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx)